# How do I loop through XML using Nokogiri to add certain parts to an array?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have this as my XML:

```
<systems>
  <system number="2" >
    <lists>
      <list critical="user" access="remote"></list>
      <list critical="root" access="local"></list>
    </lists>
    <os system="linux" basebox="AddBaseBox" ></os>
    <networks>
      <network name="homeonly" ></network>
      <network name="homeonly2"></network>
    </networks>
  </system>
</systems>
```

I want to add them to an array so I wrote this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("boxesconfig.xml"))

doc.search('//systems/system').each do |system|
    list = []
    networks = []
    systemNumber  = system.at('@number').text
    os  = system.at('//os/@system').text
    base = system.at('//os/@basebox').text
   
    list << { "critical" => system.at('//lists/list/@critical').text, "access" => system.at('//lists/list/@access').text}
    networks << { "network" => system.at('//networks/network/@name').text}
    puts list
    puts systemNumber
    puts os
    puts networks    
end
```

The output I receive is:

```
{"critical"=>"user", "access"=>"remote"}
2
linux
{"network"=>"homeonly"}
```

I want to have multiple lists and multiple networks displayed in the array. What am I doing wrong?

The output I want is:

```
{"critical"=>"user", "access"=>"remote"}
{"root"=>"user", "access"=>"local"}
2
linux
{"network"=>"homeonly"}
{"network"=>"homeonly2"}
```

Comment: show your expected output... so that I can give you some code to get you started,, Your code has not like much Rubyish.. :)

Comment: Doh my bad. 2 seconds i'll post the expeced output

Comment: added the output I want to receive

Comment: I hope you got your answer...:)

Comment: Yes Sixy4Bit answered it nicely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokogiri allows you to access the XML using CSS selectors. When your selectors match more than one thing, Nokogiri returns an array of those things. Here, we are using Ruby's `Array#collect` method to return a new array of items based on what the block returns:

```
lists = system.css('lists list').collect do |list| 
  { 'critical' => list['critical'], 'access' => list['access'] } 
end

networks = system.css('networks network').collect do |network| 
  { 'network' => network['name'] } 
end
```

This should give you the output you are looking for.

Comment: That's gone and done it :) cheers will remember css selectors in the future, i literally thought i shouldn't look into it because it'd be looking at CSS elements or something haha.

Comment: Just to be clear, this approach doesn't require CSS selectors; you can also use `system.xpath('//lists/list')` and `system.xpath('//networks/network')`.

Comment: @Sixty4Bit: The CSS you provided is technically not equivalent. To specify child elements use `lists > list` instead of `lists list`.

Comment: @MarkThomas Thank you for the clarification. Does `lists list` match any list that is a descendent of lists? IE it would be the equivalent of `system.xpath('//lists//list')`

Comment: @Sixty4Bit Yes. Note that you can use Nokogiri's `xpath_for()` to see how any arbitrary CSS is converted into XPath internally.